# Calculating combinations with colors

Tags: combinations

I need to know how many combinations there are possible from 10 balls with 5 colors. All colors must be in there, so in every combination there have to be 5 colors. Amount doesnt matter.

Any tips? Thanks!

---

### EDIT

Updated question, I need to know every possibility now. So this is a valid combination:

5 red
0 green
0 blue
0 white
0 black

4 red
1 green
1 blue
1 white
1 black

etc.

Comment: I've been playing with stuff like [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator-old.html) and the formulas it lists, but I just don't really know what I'm doing, ha.

Comment: The two examples you give don't add up to 10 balls. Do you mean not all 10 balls have to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Considering 5 different color balls as a single entity. You have 6 different entity. This will give 6! combinations. Now 5 balls in the single big entity can be combined giving you 5! combination with each 6!
So total of 5! * 6!

I am a newbie here. So it might be not correct.